# C# BinaryWriter Save as PFM image file

Tags: c#, image, file, binarywriter

Trying to write a 32bit float RGB image as a pfm file, but not sure how to interpret this explanation.  (http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/PFM/)

> The format begins with three lines of text specifying the image size
> and type, and then continues with raw binary image data for the rest
> of the file. The text header of a .pfm file takes the following form:
>
> [type] [xres] [yres] [byte_order] Each of the three lines of text ends
> with a 1-byte Unix-style carriage return: 0x0a in hex, not the
> Windows/DOS CR/LF combination. The "[type]" is one of "PF" for a
> 3-channel RGB color image, or "Pf" for a monochrome single-channel
> image. "[xres] [yres]" indicates the x and y resolutions of the image.
> "[byte_order]" is a number used to indicate the byte order within the
> file. A positive number (e.g. "1.0") indicates big-endian, with the
> most significant byte of each 4-byte float first. If the number is
> negative (e.g. "-1.0") this indicates little-endian, with the least
> significant byte first. There are no comments in these files. For
> example:
>
> PF 768 512
> -1.0
> Indicates an RGB color image, 768 by 512 pixels, with little-endian byte order.
>
> After the final carriage return the file proceeds with a series of
> three 4-byte IEEE 754 single precision floating point numbers for each
> pixel, specified in left to right, bottom to top order.

C# My current Code:

```
        using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write("PF");
                writer.Write((byte)0x0a);
                writer.Write(((int)texture.Width).ToString());
                writer.Write((byte)0x20);
                writer.Write(((int)texture.Height).ToString());
                writer.Write((byte)0x0a);
                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                {
                    writer.Write("-1.0");
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write("1.0");
                }
                writer.Write((byte)0x0a);
                for (int i = 0; i < texture.Length; i++)
                {
                    writer.Write((float)texture[i].R));
                    writer.Write((float)texture[i].G));
                    writer.Write((float)texture[i].B));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is a space between [xres] and [yres]

Comment: Now the files opens in Photoshop, but is just black, but not sure how I am going to write "raw binary image data for the rest of the file" with StreamWriter.

Comment: Actually I'd say stick with the `BinaryWriter`. But format the header as a string, convert that string to bytes, and write them as a byte array. Specifically don't use the `BinaryWriter.Write(string)` overload, that does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working verison:

```
    using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            string str = $"PF\n{(int)texture.Width} {(int)texture.Height}\n-1.0\n";

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);

            writer.Write(bytes);

            for (int i = 0; i < texture.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.Write((float)texture[i].R);
                writer.Write((float)texture[i].G);
                writer.Write((float)texture[i].B);
            }
        }
    }
```